# Is it normal to have a bootstrap template without using the grid system?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm really confused and annoyed. I've spent a few hours learning bootstrap with videos and like, and they create and space out all of their elements using `col` classes. For example, to get two elements to span across one page on the mobile width you simply say:

```
<div class = 'col-xs-6'> content </div> <div class = 'col-xs-6'> content </div>
```

Seems like a good and intuitive way to build. And yet, when I click on the source of [templates such as this](http://byrushan.com/projects/black-pearl/Template/) I see that **cols are only used about 8 times**.

Why not? What reasoning is behind this, and the benefit of defining your own widths? I also see that widths are manually set in px

```
.media-object, .poster-pic {
    width: 45px;
    padding: 3px;
    background: #FFF;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

despite it being a responsive template. I just hate this. I think I'm understanding the framework, I look at a real life example and it seems to be barely using bootstrap. A few `hide-xs` classes, but that's it. Now I feel building 'properly' with bootstrap and its grid system is unprofessional. Is this the case? **Why on that template have they done something completely alien?**

Answer (score 1):

There are a few likely reasons why the developer of that template didn't use more of Bootstrap's grid.

1. Bootstrap was added as an afterthought to a template already in development to create commercial appeal or to resolve certain issues.
2. Bootstrap's grid doesn't really allow for fixed-width sidebars, as this template has. The developer may have wanted to accommodate fixed-sized content for simplicity. Bootstrap's columns change width more often than may have been acceptable.
3. The developer may not have been very knowledgeable with regard to Bootstrap and its capabilities, and may have been more comfortable writing most of the layout from scratch. There's a learning curve to any new system or library, of course.

I agree with your thoughts, and for that reason I'd avoid a template written like this. It'll be more difficult to customize and maintain than one built to take full advantage of Bootstrap, using more consistent markup. Another reason is because their homepage isn't loading, and its title reads "Coming soon". Not terribly confidence-inspiring.

Answer (score 0):

Don't view Bootstrap as a choice. 
It may have a lot of goods things at some point for you but also it could have a lot of bad points at you. 
But it always possible for individual to full pieces of Bootstrap and to customize aspects of it to get something that looks fresh, either by digging into the code or using some [resources](http://bootsnipp.com/) .

It's perfectly acceptable to use the grid system but design your own components. Or ditch the grid and use their components. It's not an either/or proposition. The only time it really gets tricky is when you decide you really want to change something, like the look and feel of a menu. The "right way" to do it isn't always readily apparent. You may have to dig pretty deep into the code, and it can be tough to make sure you're changes aren't breaking something else. But that's still better than not having an example to pull from at all.

I think the only mistake you can make is not taking a thorough look at what Bootstrap can provide you.